# How to set and get system time using assembly language?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I writed a code, that should set system time on 00h,00min,00sec.

```
    mov ah,2dh
    mov cx,0000h
    mov dx,0000h
    int 21h

    mov ah,2Ch
    int 21h     ;dh = sec
```

But it doesent works, when i check it in turbo-debugger, after geting time with int21h/fn2ch i see wrong time, not that i set.
Please help.

Comment: Start by checking if the function returns `ah = 0xFF = invalid time, system time not changed`; and if it does try `hour = 1` (e.g. maybe hour is meant to be a value from 1 to 24 and 0 is not valid). Note: Ralph Brown's Interrupt List doesn't say what the parameters actually are (e.g. if `hour` is 0 to 23, or 1 to 24, or 1 to 12 with high bit as AM/PM flag, or if they're supposed to be in BCD or not, or ...) so I don't know what it's supposed to be.

Comment: When i set time, al sets in 00, that means time set correcetly. I tried hour = 1,but it still not works

Comment: In that case, as far as I can tell it should work (assuming you're running it in an "MS-DOS" environment), and I'd be tempted to (e.g.) dig into the source code for DOSemu to see if it implements the function/s correctly.

Comment: same here, Int 21h/2ch (get time) works fine for me, while 21h/2dh is setting AL to 0, but not the time. Probably an issue(or maybe some time sync feature with the host?) in DosBox (i'm using version 0,74)